# onclick form send via ajax no page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I've been racking my brains for days looking at examples and trying out different things to try and get my form to submit with Ajax without a page refresh. And Its not even sending the data now.. I don't know what I'm doing wrong..Can someone run through my ajax and form please.

Toid is the users id and newmsg is the text in which the user submits. The two values get sent to the insert.php page.

I would really appreate the help. I'm new to Ajax, and I look at some of it and don't have a clue. If I finally got it working, It may help me realize what I've done wrong. I am looking up tutorials and watching videos..but it can be very time consuming for something that would be simple to someone in the know on here. It maybe that I've got the wrong idea on the ajax and it makes no sense at all, sorry about that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("form#myform").submit(function() {
homestatus()      
event.preventDefault();
var toid = $("#toid").attr("toid");
var content = $("#newmsg").attr("content");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insert.php",
        data: "toid="+content+"&newmsg="+ newmsg,
        success: function(){
           }
    });
    });
return false;
});
</script>


<form id="myform"  method="POST"  class="form_statusinput">
<input type="hidden"  name="toid" id="toid" value="<?php echo $user1_id ?>">
<input class="input" name="newmsg" id="newmsg" placeholder="Say something" autocomplete="off">
<div id="button_block">
<input type="submit" id="button" value="Feed" onsubmit="homestatus(); return false" >
</div>
</form>
```

INSERT.PHP

```
$user1_id=$_SESSION['id'];
if(isset($_POST['toid'])){

if($_POST['toid']==""){$_POST['toid']=$_SESSION['id'];}

if(isset($_POST['newmsg'])&isset($_POST['toid'])){
if($_POST['toid']==$_SESSION['id']){
rawfeeds_user_core::create_streamitem("1",$_SESSION['id'],$_POST['newmsg'],"1",$_POST['toid']);
}else{
rawfeeds_user_core::create_streamitem("3",$_SESSION['id'],$_POST['newmsg'],"1",$_POST['toid']);
```

Comment: What/where is your `homestatus()` function ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using firebug to identify bugs in your code. It's a really good companion for developing javascript. Nearly all of your bugs led to error messages in the firebug console.

You had several errors in your code, here is the corrected version:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#myform").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var toid = $("#toid").val();
        var newmsg = $("#newmsg").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insert.php",
            data: "toid=" + content + "&newmsg=" + newmsg,
            success: function(){alert('success');}
        });
    });
});
```

And here the corrected html:

```
<form id="myform"  method="POST"  class="form_statusinput">
<input type="hidden"  name="toid" id="toid" value="<?php echo $user1_id; ?>">
<input class="input" name="newmsg" id="newmsg" placeholder="Say something" autocomplete="off">
<div id="button_block">
<input type="submit" id="button" value="Feed">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your code gives me the success message yet the user feed doesn't update or send the indo to my database. My original form without the ajax submitted to the insert.php fine with the action button. So it must be the ajax.

Comment: Then the ajax call definitely worked and your insert.php got invoked. Maybe you have another bug on the server side.

Comment: Actually/..Its working..But its not adding the new status unless I refresh the page.

Comment: I don't know, try debugging it. Firebug is helping you there, too, with firebug you see the ajax requests occurring in the background and the answer of your server. Try to install firebug and then use `print_r` to debug your php.

Comment: Its working..Just the page isn't adding the new comment. I have to refresh it to see it..Ajax is pointless if it doesn't update.. How can I rectify this.

Comment: then you have to add javascript code that is adding the new status. you wanted to use ajax for the form submission :) ajax is not a magician

Comment: Something like obj.innerHTML = obj.innerHTML + "STATUS CONTENT HERE";

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14206/discussion-between-dave-and-stefreak)

Answer (score 2):

Actually `onsubmit event` has to be used with `form` so instead of

```
<input type="submit" id="button" value="Feed" onsubmit="homestatus(); return false" >
```

it could be

```
<form id="myform"  method="POST"  class="form_statusinput" onsubmit="homestatus();">
```

and return the `true` or `false` from the function/handler, i.e.

```
function homestatus()
{
    //...
    if(condition==true) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Since you are using `jQuery` it's better to use as follows

```
$("form#myform").on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var toid = $("#toid").val(); // get value
    var content = $("#newmsg").val(); // get value
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insert.php",
        data: "toid=" + toid + "&newmsg=" + content,
        success: function(data){
            // do something with data
        }
    });

});
```

In this case your form should be as follows

```
<form id="myform"  method="POST"  class="form_statusinput">
    ...
</form>
```

and `input` fields should have a valid `type` and `value` attribute, [**Html form and Input**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html).

I think you should read more about `jQuery`.

**Reference :** [**jQuery val**](http://api.jquery.com/val/) and [**jQuery Ajax**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 1):

change the form to this

```
<form id="myform" ... onsubmit="homestatus(); return false">
```

you don't need the `onsubmit` attribute on the submit button, but on the form element instead

homestatus might be out of scope

```
function homestatus () {
    var toid = $("#toid").attr("toid");
    var content = $("#newmsg").attr("content");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insert.php",
        data: "toid="+content+"&newmsg="+ newmsg,
        success: function(){
           }
    });
}
```

Comment: Its still the same..Its refreshing and not submitting the data into the database and the users feed.

Comment: Its not submitting at all now. When  click my button it does nothing. Do I need to add any jquery links in my header?

Comment: did you check the console, you might be getting an error, and your ajax is not doing much after it is done

Comment: I get these errors toid=undefined&newmsg=undefined It also says undefined in the fieldlist

Answer (score 1):

This isn't tested, but try this (I annotated some stuff using comments)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("form#myform").submit(function(event) {
        // not sure what this does, so let's take it out of the equation for now, it may be causing errors
        //homestatus()      
        // needed to declare event as a param to the callback function
        event.preventDefault(); 
        // I think you want the value of these fields
        var toid = $("#toid").val(); 
        var content = $("#newmsg").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insert.php",
            data: "toid="+toid +"&newmsg="+ content,
            success: function(){
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

});

</script>


<form id="myform"  method="POST"  class="form_statusinput">
<input type="hidden"  name="toid" id="toid" value="<?php echo $user1_id ?>">
<input class="input" name="newmsg" id="newmsg" placeholder="Say something" autocomplete="off">
<div id="button_block">
<input type="submit" id="button" value="Feed" / >
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time Jeremy. Like I said. I have no knowledge..I am however trying..Like anything else tho. We all have to start somewhere. 
I remember once upon a time when I was hopeless at php. But I'm getting there.

Comment: It doesn't do anything, I will post my insert.php into the question.

Comment: no, that's not the issue. Try again, i didn't notice you had an onsubmit on your submit button, remove that.

Comment: Still no luck. Think I may take the time to look into it more. Must be something I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It's a lot easier to let `.serialize()` do the work of serializing the form data.

The submit handler also needs `event` as a formal parameter, otherwise an error will be thrown (event will be undefined).

With a few other changes, here is the whole thing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#myform").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        homestatus();
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insert.php",
            data: formData,
            success: function(data) {
                //...
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

<form id="myform" class="form_statusinput">
    <input type="hidden" name="toid" id="toid" value="<?php echo $user1_id ?>">
    <input class="input" name="newmsg" id="newmsg" placeholder="Say something" autocomplete="off">
    <div id="button_block">
        <input type="submit" id="button" value="Feed" >
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are omitting some of your code, the problem is this line:

```
homestatus()
```

You never defined this function, so the submit throws an error.

Comment: So for instance I need something like this function homestatus(content){
$.post("insert.php", { newmsg: content } );

Comment: No, you already have the code for the ajax request. You just need to remove all references to homestatus()

Answer (score -3):

You may want to take a look at jQuery ([www.jquery.com](http://www.jquery.com)) or another js framework.
Such frameworks do most of the stuff you normally have to do by hand.
There are also a bunch of nice helper functions for sending form data or modifying html elements