# onclick function using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In my code having two radio buttons in form like

```
<input type="radio" required="required" id="bt" name="bt" value="1" checked="checked" onclick="window.location='<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>';" /> <span>Test1</span>

<input type="radio" required="required" id="bt" name="bt" onclick="Clear()" value="2" /> <span>Test2</span>
```

when i click on Test2 radio button the form having  value will clear, for that i wrote code its working fine

```
<script>
function Clear() {
    document.getElementsByName("one")[0].value = "";
    document.getElementsByName("two")[0].value = "";
    document.getElementsByName("three")[0].value = "";
}     
</script>
```

with this form with values cleared.But when i click on "Test1" radio button the form values will come automatically.right now iam sessions using

```
onclick="window.location='<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>';"
```

for this it is coming but page is refreshing how to take it this code to ajax, i mean need to get values when i click on radio button without refreshing the page

Comment: Refer to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588507/onclick-form-send-via-ajax-no-page-refresh

Comment: is it not possible to add window.location function in ajax @amy

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use window.location.href in ajax as:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        url: '/users',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(payload),
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            console.log(jqXHR.status);
            window.location.href= "/someUrl.html";
        }
    });
```

Note that: window.location.href will not reload the page if there's an anchor (#) in the URL

Comment: here what is url:'/users' @amy

Comment: URL: Specifies the URL to send the request to. Default is the current page

Answer (score 0):

Here i wrote code for getting values of radio button without page refresh:

html code:

```
<input type="radio"  name="bt"  id="bt" onclick = "MyAlert()" value="blue"/>Blue  <br/>
<input type="radio"  name="bt" id="bt" onclick = "MyAlert()" value="red"/>Red
```

ajax script:

```
function MyAlert()  {  
    var radio =$('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
    var pass_data = {
            'radio' : radio,
        };
        $.ajax({
            url : "radio-value.php",
            type : "POST",
            data: pass_data,
            success : function(data) {
                // alert radio value here
                alert(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

radio-value.php file:

```
<?php echo $bt =$_POST['radio']; ?>
```

Hope this helps.