# Problem with sending requests to Controller by Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cakephp

I have a problem with validation in my contact view. The validation is in my Controller and I'm trying to sending there my form data through AJAX. This is how it looks like my AJAX code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.contact_form').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        let name = $('#name').val();
        let title = $('#title').val();
        let mail = $('#mail').val();
        let text = $('#text').val();
        $.ajax({ 
            type:'POST',
            url:'../Strona/contact',
            dataType:'json',
            crossDomain:false, 
            cashe:false, 
            contentType:"text/javascript",
            data:{
                name: name,
                title: title,
                mail: mail,
                text: text
             }
        })
        .done(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            if(data.res === 'yes'){
                console.log(data);
                $('.contact_form').html(data.list);
            }else{
                $.each(data.list,function(k,v){
                    console.log(data);
                    $('.error_'+k).append(v);
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

And validation in my Controller:

```
if($this->request->is('post')){
    $data = $this->data;

    $errors=array();

    if(!$data['Contact']['name']){$errors['name'] = 'Bitte geben Sie einen Namen ein';}
    if(!$data['Contact']['email']){$errors['email'] = 'Bitte geben Sie eine E-Mail-Adresse ein';}
    if(!$data['Contact']['title']){$errors['title'] = 'Bitte geben Sie einen Titel ein';}
    if(!$data['Contact']['description']){$errors['description'] = 'Bitte geben Sie eine Nachricht ein';}
    if(count($errors) > 0){
        $result = array('res'=>'no','list'=>$errors);
        $el['Result'] = $result;
        $el['Contact'] = $data;
        $el['Contact'] = $el['Contact']['Contact'];
        $this->set('errors');
        $this->set('_serialize', array('errors'));
        $this->set('el',$el);
    }else{
        $result = array('res'=>'yes','list'=>'Vielen Dank für das Senden einer E-Mail');
        $txt = $data['Contact']['name'].'<br>'.$data['Contact']['description'];
        $subject = $data['Contact']['title'];
        $from = $data['Contact']['email'];

        $this->Ajax->mailsend($txt, $subject, $from);
        $data['result'] = $result;
        $this->Contact->save($data);
        $this->Session->setFlash('Nachricht gesendet');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'contact/'));
    }
}
```

When i click the button to send message and there is empty input an error should show, but there's nothing happening. Request was not send to the Controller.

I think maybe the problem is in my wiev.

```
<form method="POST" action="" class="contact_form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="data[Contact][name]" value="<?php echo $el['Contact']['name']; ?>" placeholder="Dein Name"/>
        <div class="error error_name"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="data[Contact][email]" value="<?php echo $el['Contact']['email']; ?>" placeholder="Deine E-Mail-Adresse"/>
        <div class="error error_email"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="data[Contact][title]" value="<?php echo $el['Contact']['title']; ?>" placeholder="Betreff"/>
        <div class="error error_title"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="describe" name="data[Contact][description]" placeholder="Deine Nachricht" rows="10"><?php echo $el['Contact']['description']; ?></textarea>
        <div class="error error_description"></div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="send" class="btn btn-primary" value="Senden">
</form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [onclick form send via ajax no page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588507/onclick-form-send-via-ajax-no-page-refresh)

Comment: A little bit. I try to used the advices and change my code. I have edited the code above. Now view after submit  don't refresh themselve, but still I have a problem with ajax. He isn't starting. The cosole.log don't give anythink.

Comment: Check the network monitor in your browser to see what happens with the request. That should narrow down where the problem lies.

Comment: Ok. I'm trying. The network give me some answears. Controller don't get the data from form. But I don't know why. I'will try to do something with this.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in my wiev. I add above.

Comment: What does your `vd` function do?

Comment: Its  just var_dump();

Answer (score 0):

You're using `$this->set('el',$el);`, but that just makes the `$el` variable available to whatever view might get rendered. Assuming that you don't have an Ajax-specific view, it may be falling back to the default Ajax view, which I think just dumps the contents of any variables that you set to be serialized. You haven't set anything to be serialized. See [JSON and XML views](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html) for how to set the `_serialized` variable, if that's how you want to go.

If you want to be more explicit, you could replace that `set` call and instead [send a string](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/controllers/request-response.html#sending-a-string-as-file) for the response:

```
$this->response->body(json_encode($el));
return $this->response;
```

Comment: I tried to do something with this _serialized variable like in the CakeBook is writen but still don't work. I have no idea's how to do it right.

Answer (score 0):

I can't yet add comments, so I'll answer from my perspective.  The AJAX event seems to be  encapsulated in a function.  If you want just to listen for the event, try taking the submit action out of the function and into a `$(document).ready();`block and it should fire. I also suggest you do your form validation in JavaScript instead of the controller.  Post back your results! Hope this helps

Comment: I change my code like you said but the validation still in controller. Now when I click the submit nothings happen.